# Copy only column header from resultset in microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to copy only 'Column Headers' from the result set in Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio but I didn't find any option. Same option is there is Oracle SQL server management. I googled about it but didn't find any thing that would help me so wanted to check if there a way to do this

Answer (score 3):

Run your query without any result-set using
    select  * from tablename where 1=2

then use "Copy with Header".This is the only way to copy only columns header.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of result into grid please use Result to text. [Result to Text - Ctrl+3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYXu7.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

No straight method as far as I know. One method is to output the result to text and copy only the header. Another trick is to execute the query without returning any results to grid by applying a false predicate like `SELECT column_list FROM yourtable WHERE 1 = 2;` then, use 'Copy with Headers' option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SET FMTONLY ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) before execute query .
It,s used to test the format of the response without actually running the query.
Choose results to grid and choose **copy with headers** option  .

Answer (score 0):

mark the table name and run alt+F1.
than you can copy directly from the cells of the Column_name table

Answer (score 0):

[SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-copy-results-grid-headers) appears to have this as a feature. It is an addon for SQL Server Management Studio but the Pro edition (which you need for this feature) will cost you US$195.

(I am not affiliated with this product)